# How do can I animate in java with the use of a timer? Should I use another method?

Tags: java, animation, timer

I am trying to animate an image to move across a jPanel. But when I try to use  a timer it just show the final position of the image.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong kind of timer. You need to use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Antonio! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!